# Plotting several plots in one figure at specific coordinates

Tags: matlab

I'm looking for a way how to plot graph at specific coordinates of a figure (maybe my terminology is not rigth). So it might look like this:

[image]

And I could draw in to figure 1. For example lines between plots etc.

If I use subplot, I would get grid layout, but I need to define position more freely. And I wouldn't be able to draw anything between those plots.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `subplot` but place the plots freely by setting their `Position` property.
So a quick example:

```
x=rand(1,100);
ax1=subplot(2,2,1);
plot(x)
ax2=subplot(2,2,2);
plot(x)
ax3=subplot(2,2,3);
plot(x)
ax4=subplot(2,2,4);
plot(x)
set(ax1,'Position',[0.05 0.75 0.35 0.2])
set(ax2,'Position',[0.1 0.45 0.35 0.2])
set(ax3,'Position',[0.15 0.15 0.35 0.2])
set(ax4,'Position',[0.6 0.45 0.35 0.2])
```

Note that the parameters are `[x y w h]` and `x=0,y=0` is in the bottom left corner. The values are normalized to `[0,1]`.

Comment: So that would solve the position problem. Thank you. Now how to draw in between those graphs?

Comment: Please consider opening a new question for this in order to reduce the clutter in the comments and to keep the questions separated. Then also give a small example of what and how do you want to plot between those graphs.

Comment: @user5022 - what you want is just not what you should Matlab use for. Think about inkscpape, Adobe Illustrator or whatever...

Comment: @thewaywewalk I need it to be automatic. Not just one picture.

Comment: @user50222 you could use a fifth axes object as big as your figure. and place the others axes above. But it's gonna be a really nasty task. I don't want to say it can't be done, but I doubt that somebody here will spend some hours to do it for you. The problem is not the placement itself, but to get it perfectly fitting with all the lines you want to draw. It seems like a good task for Latex' Tikz and pgfplots though, are you familiar with these?

Comment: if you set the position of the axes by yourself, you'd better use the low level functions `ax1=axes;ax2=axes; etc ...` ... instead of `subplot` (`subplot` does other things in the background which (i) you do not need and (ii) will mess up your layout if its called after any position change).

Comment: @user50222. As @lmNt said, consider asking another question for your next request, and show what you try by yourself too to increase your chance of a good answer. If you only want _straight lines_ between your subplots, you can get away without a master background axes, try to practice a bit with `annotation('line',x,y)`.